# Coordinate System from a 3D unit vector

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems

I am currently working through the "Physically Based Rendering" book ([pbrt](https://pbrt.org/)) and found a passage that I am not sure if it is correct.

In [this](https://www.pbr-book.org/4ed/Geometry_and_Transformations/Vectors#CoordinateSystemfromaVector) section, they describe how to construct a local coordinate system from a single 3D unit vector $v$, computing two perpendicular unit vectors (u, w):

$$
u = (\frac{1-v_x^2}{1+v_z}, -\frac{v_x v_y}{1+v_z}, -v_x) \\
w = (-\frac{v_x v_y}{1+v_z}, \frac{1-v_y^2}{1+v_z}, -v_y)
$$

I tried to derive it and could not get there. I also checked if the proposed vectors are in fact unit vectors (with $v = (\frac{1}{\sqrt3}, \frac{1}{\sqrt3} \frac{1}{\sqrt3})$) and found that they are not.

Do you have an intuition what is wrong here? Or if they are right, could you proof this or link me to a source that can? I could not find anything.

Comment: I guess it's a typo in the book. u and w are not perpendicular to v.

Comment: The code sample also contradicts the formula.

Comment: @DavidK Oh i think I found the contradiction. Little bit hard to spot that "1 -" should not be in the numerator but in front. Thats what got me

Comment: Now that you mention it, I see that that error is corrected in the code sample.

Comment: @DavidK yes the code has it correct. Thanks for your hint. And I also found that they included this error in the Errata for the 4th Edition of the book. No idea why they didnt fix it in the online edition of the book. Maybe on their todo

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a typo and should actually be:

$$
u = (1-\frac{v_x^2}{1+v_z}, -\frac{v_x v_y}{1+v_z}, -v_x) \\
w = (-\frac{v_x v_y}{1+v_z}, 1-\frac{v_y^2}{1+v_z}, -v_y)
$$

These vectors are normalized and perpendicular to each other and $v$.